# Matlab enforce variable accuracy

Tags: matlab

I have two double arrays that are of equal size but one always has the following format:

```
A1 = 0.0756    0.0368    0.0124    0.0024    0.0002    0.0000    0.0000
```

while the other one is:

```
A2 = 0.0797    0.0368    0.0120    0.0024    0.0004         0         0
```

I want to enforce the last two elements to be of the same accuracy, that is be `0.0000` instead of `0`. Trying the naïve approach of `A2(7) = 0.0000` does not work, although `A2(7) = A1(7)` does the trick.

How can I archive this a bit more cleverly?

Comment: Why do you want this? If its because some output requires it you should look into printing commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Careful! I think you will find the `A1(7) == 0` returns `false`.

What exactly do you mean by the same accuracy? Internally matlab uses the same precision for every element of both of your arrays (they're all doubles). It is just displaying them differently.

Try the following commands:

```
A1(7);
format long g
A1(7);
```

and I think you'll find that in fact `A1(7)` isn't `0` and furthermore is also accurate to far more than the 4 decimal points you are seeing.

So the question is, do you actually want to round off to 4 decimal places? Or do you just want to display up to 4 decimal places? I image you want the latter, so have a look at `sprintf`

Comment: I want the element 6, 7 to be 0.0000, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The numbers actually already have the desired precision. If you want you can print them with any amount of digits you like (Though typically only about the first fourteen will be significant).

For this you can use the various print commands, however if you want to change the *default* way numbers are displayed, your simple options are quite limited.

Check `help format` for the things you can choose from.
If you always want to show a minmum number of decimals, I believe your only choice is:

```
format shorteng
```